# how to create multiple table on UITableViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview

i would like to create multiple table view on UITableViewController please anyone assist me.thank's.

Comment: Igor's answer is right. Just try it.

Comment: @ReinhardMänner Instead of posting such a comment you should up vote the answer if you think it is helpful.

Comment: I did so, before I commented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can not do this with UITableViewController. Create UIViewController and add some UITableView on it.

Or maybe using some table sections will be better solution for you?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10320857)

Comment: why do you think so? I've answer that author can not use the UITableViewController to work with multiple tables, and propose the decision: use UIViewController with several UITableView. Where did you found the critique here?

Answer (score 0):

Use tableView's tableHeaderView and tableFooterView properties.
You can add as many tableViews as you wanted,as long as the superView of them is a tableHeaderView/tableFooterView of your UITableViewController's tableView.
But this is not a good approach.